# fatal error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following code:

```
public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       

    int c = 10000;
    String ar[][] = new String[100][c];
    for(int i = 0; i < c;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 100;j++)     
            ar[j][i] = i+"";    
    }

    for(;;){}
}
}
```

When I attempt to run it I get this error. The strange thing is that the error does not occur when I comment out `for(;;){}`.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000642949da, pid=6420, tid=2424
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x4d49da]
```

Comment: Hmmm... This error only occurs when c is large. When I reduce it to 1000 the error does not occur. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: No error with OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)